# Why does this if else statement work but not this Switch statement

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, switch-statement

I have this if else statement that runs perfectly fine on my ExamController.cs but I wanted to use a switch statement to make it more easier to read. The only thing I added to the switch statement was the ExamId.

How come this if else statement works but not my switch case. The error has to do with the return but I didn't make any changes to the return.

```
if (model.SearchType == "School")
{
    result = FindExams((e) => e.School.School_Name.Contains(model.SearchInput));
}
else if (model.SearchType == "Exam Date")
{
    result = FindExams((e) => e.Exam.ExamDate >= model.StartDate.Date && e.Exam.ExamDate <= model.EndDate.Date);
}
else if (model.SearchType == "District")
{
    result = FindExams((e) => e.District.Name.Contains(model.SearchInput));
}
else if (model.SearchType == "ID")
{
    result = FindExams((e) => e.Student.ID.Contains(model.SearchInput));
}
else if (model.SearchType == "First Name")
{
    result = FindExams((e) => e.Student.FirstName.Contains(model.SearchInput));
}
else if (model.SearchType == "Last Name")
{
    result = FindExams((e) => e.Student.LastName.Contains(model.SearchInput));
}

return result.OrderByDescending(r => r.ExamDate);
```

**Switch Statement**

```
switch (model.SearchType)
{
    case "School":
        result = this.FindExams((e) => e.School.School_Name.Contains(model.SearchInput));
        break;
    case "ExamDate":
        result = FindExams((e) => e.Exam.ExamDate >= model.StartDate.Date && e.Exam.ExamDate <= model.EndDate.Date);
        break;
    case "District":
        result = this.FindExams((e) => e.District.Name.Contains(model.SearchInput));
        break;
    case "ID":
        result = this.FindExams((e) => e.Student.ID.Contains(model.SearchInput));
        break;
    case "First Name":
        result = this.FindExams((e) => e.Student.FirstName.Contains(model.SearchInput));
        break;
    case "Last Name":
        result = this.FindExams((e) => e.Student.LastName.Contains(model.SearchInput));
        break;
    case "Exam Id":
        int examId = int.Parse(model.SearchInput);
        result = this.FindExams((e) => e.Exam.Exam_Id == examId);
        break;
}

return result.OrderByDescending(r => r.ExamDate);
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure if that's the issue but one of the if statements checks for `Exam Date`, while on of the cases in the switch checks for `ExamDate`. Also you should probably add a `default` case and a null check for `result`.

Comment: was just going to post that comment -- also you're missing a default case, but that's not _causing_ your problem, but it _does_ hide it

Comment: What is the value of _model.SearchType_ when the code fails? Use the debugger to check the value.

Comment: *sighs* I want to punch myself in the face. Thank you, it was because I didn't add a space lol. Btw how would I add a default case that would show me cause of a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

The two code snippets differ at these lines:

`else if (model.SearchType == "Exam Date")`

And

`case "ExamDate":`

As you can see they check two different strings.
It should be:

`case "Exam Date":`